# Generic types within an interface for a function type

Tags: typescript, generics, types, interface

When creating an interface for an options object, I'm trying to allow the user to specify a function with an explicit return type and a generic argument type. This is possible if you haven't defined a type for the function beforehand, but I can't figure out how to do it for a function type you've already defined.

For instance, this works just fine:

```js
interface Options {
  // Other options...
  converterFunction: <T>(rawData: T) => [];
}
```

But this, which seems like a reasonable syntax, does not.

```js
type ConverterFunction<T> = (rawData: T) => [];

interface Options {
  // Other options...
  converterFunction: <T>ConverterFunction<T>; // TypeScript is unhappy
}
```

Making the interface generic doesn't solve my problem, and I'd like to use my pre-defined types instead of re-defining them arbitrarily.

Comment: The type `ConverterFunction<T>` does not refer to a generic function, so you can't use it when defining `Options`.  You'd probably need something like [generic values](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17574) to programmatically turn a generic type referring to a specific function into a specific type referring to a generic function.  But the language doesn't support that now.  You'll have to redefine your types as far as I can tell.

Comment: Thanks, @jcalz. so to clarify, if a generic function is named, it’s no longer generic?

Comment: Not exactly.  `type Foo = <T>(x: T)=>T` is a non-generic type alias to a generic function, while `type Bar<T> = (x: T)=>T` is a generic type alias to a non-generic function.  You can have both: `type Baz<T> = <U>(x: T, y: U) => [T, U]`.  The issue is that there are two distinct types of generics in TS which differ according to the scope of the generic parameter and who specifies it.  Generic functions have a parameter on the call signature and the caller specifies it.  Generic type aliases/interfaces/classes have a parameter in the definition and it is specified when you refer to it later.

Comment: Thank you! I switched to a different account so I don’t yet think I have the ability to upvote because of reputation, but that was very helpful clarification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A type that uses another generic type must either passes a concrete type, or be generic itself.

And `<T>Type<T>` is not a valid syntax.

```
type ConverterFunction<T> = (rawData: T) => [];

interface Options<T> {
  converterFunction: ConverterFunction<T>; // TypeScript is happy
}

const options: Options<string> = {
  converterFunction(aString) {
    return []
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=13&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwG4QE7DQMQK4IMbACWiAPACoB8UAvFABSoCGA7gCKPCMBcUZAlDSoBtALoBuALAAoaYQQZUAM0Z5oAeTBFEAZ3JUA3tKhQ8iFOiy4CxBD3jI0CnPi0I9YqAHpPvcBADKeKiEmlCE2lAAFoxgYCDSAL7S0qYI2sBQcJo22jwarrrpwQgA5lS0hlLGqeZOVq50jP7AxSUClcbGqBDA2KgIUKJGUElSo9JAA)

---

> *If the type is not named, you can define a function with a generic parameter, but if it is named, it seems this is not possible. I’m asking if this is indeed the case*

It all depends on what level you want the generic passed in.

If you know it at the time you use the type, then it goes on the type.

```
type ConverterFunction<T> = (rawData: T) => T[];
const fn: ConverterFunction<string> = a => [a]
fn('a') // ['a']
```

Or if you want the generic type inferred by the function itself, then put it on the function.

```
type ConverterFunction = <T>(rawData: T) => T[];
const fn: ConverterFunction = (a: string) => [a]
fn('a') // ['a']
```

After reading your comments, it sounds like you want this second one.

Comment: Why is it then that `<T>(rawData: T) => []` is valid syntax? This seems to allow you to specify the type when you define the function rather than type-wide.

Comment: `<T>(args: ArgsType) => ReturnType` is how you declare a generic function type. If the type already has a name, the generic parameter goes on the end. That's just how the syntax works. In both cases, it simply declares the generic parameter.

Comment: Yes, I’m not questioning the syntax. If the type is not named, you can define a function with a generic parameter, but if it is named, it seems this is not possible. I’m asking if this is indeed the case.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I’ve switched accounts so I don’t yet have the reputation to upvote you, but I’ve marked this as the answer.